# Will my current save be updated if I go do unfinished stranger missions?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I want to finish stranger missions in Red Dead Redemption 2, but I am not sure if I go back to a previous save the the progress will update on my current save.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same with many other games that have saved game slots.

Each saved game continues from the point at which the story is saved.

If you go back to an earlier saved game and complete a stranger mission and then go back to a later saved game, then the progress you made in an earlier saved game won't have any effect because each load is from a set point.

There are two exceptions here:

- If you choose to replay a mission from the "Story" screen (in which case you get to replay and complete that mission using a default horse and loadout, and any pickups/stats you build in that mission will be lost when the mission completes)
- If you complete a mission series that ends up with you gaining an Xbox or Playstation trophy - when you gain a trophy, it can't be taken away, even when you change back to another save game slot.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a previous save it will not update current save a new save will need to be created in order to update progression. If you don't want to lose progress just go back to the place of the stranger missions if possible.